# Spring webflow cleaning form fields

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I use the same bean field, a string called email, for different purposes (register, recovery password, login). So, I wish navigate between views/flows and bean fields must clean automatically, but this behavior don't happen.

It's a JSF2/Spring project

**Flow definition**

```
<var name="viewScope.loginFields" class="es.project.viewBean.ConnectionFields" />

<view-state id="login" view="login.xhtml" model="loginFields">
    <transition on="entry" to="connect"/>
    <transition on="recoveryPass" to="recovery" />
</view-state>


<view-state id="recovery" view="recovery.xhtml" model="loginFields">
    <transition on="return" to="login" />
    <transition on="sendPass" to="recoveryPass" />
</view-state>
```

**Bean definition**

```
@Service("loginFields")
public class ConnectionFields implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static Logger logger=LogManager.getLogger(ConnectionFields.class);

@NotNull(message="{field.notEmpty.validation}")
@Email(message="{field.email.validation}")
private String email;

@NotNull(message="{field.notEmpty.validation}")
@Size(min=6,max=12,message="{field.size.validation}")
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$",message="{field.onlyAlpha.validation}")
private String password;

@NotNull(message="{field.notEmpty.validation}")
@Size(min=6,max=12,message="{field.size.validation}")
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$",message="{field.onlyAlpha.validation}")
private String passwordRepeated;

@NotNull(message="{field.notEmpty.validation}")
@Email(message="{field.email.validation}")
private String emailRepeated;
    ...........
    ...........
    ...........
  }
```

**recovery.xhtml**

```
    <h:form id="formRecovery">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="containerFormRecovery" styleClass="containerFormRecovery">
            <p:focus />
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="formRecovery-row">
                    <h:outputLabel for="email" value="#{msg['email.txt']}" />
                    <h:inputText id="email" value="#{loginFields.email}" title="#{msg['email.txt.title']}" alt="#{msg['email.txt.alt']}" styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'invalid'}" size="35" tabindex="1">
                        <f:validateBean for="email" />
                        <p:ajax event="blur" update="@this emailError"/>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:message for="email" id="emailError" styleClass="messageError" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="formRecovery-row">
                    <p:captcha id="captcha" theme="white" requiredMessage="#{msg['captcha.required']}" tabindex="2">

                    </p:captcha>
                    <h:message for="captcha" id="captchaError" styleClass="messageError"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="containerRecoveryButtons" styleClass="containerRecoveryButtons">
                    <h:commandButton value="#{msg['send.btn']}" title="#{msg['send.btn.title']}" alt="#{msg['send.btn.title']}" action="sendPass" tabindex="3" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:commandLink value="#{msg['return.btn']}" title="#{msg['return.btn.title']}" alt="#{msg['return.btn.alt']}" action="return" tabindex="4" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

**login.xthml**

```
                <h:form id="formLogin">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="containerFormLogin" styleClass="containerFormLogin">

                <p:focus />
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="formLogin-row">
                        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="#{msg['email.txt']}" />
                        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{loginFields.email}" title="#{msg['email.txt.title']}" alt="#{msg['email.txt.alt']}" styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'invalid'}" size="35" tabindex="2">
                            <f:validateBean for="email" />
                            <p:ajax event="blur" update="@this emailError" />
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:message for="email" id="emailError" styleClass="messageError" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="formLogin-row">
                        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="#{msg['pass.txt']}" />
                        <p:password id="password" value="#{loginFields.password}" title="#{msg['pass.txt.title']}" alt="#{msg['pass.txt.alt']}"
                            styleClass="#{component.valid ? '' : 'invalid'}" size="35" tabindex="3">
                            <f:validateBean for="password" />
                            <p:ajax event="blur" update="@this passwordError" />
                        </p:password>
                        <h:message for="password" id="passwordError" styleClass="messageError"  />
                </h:panelGroup>

                <p>
                    <h:outputLabel for="remember" value="#{msg['rememberSession.msg.check']}" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="remember" value="#{loginFields.remember}" tabindex="4" title="#{msg['rememberSession.title.check']}" />
                </p>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="containerLoginButtons" styleClass="containerLoginButtons">
                    <h:commandButton value="#{msg['login.long.btn']}" action="entry" tabindex="5" title="#{msg['login.long.btn.title']}" alt="#{msg['login.long.btn.alt']}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
            <p>
                <h:form>
                    <h:commandLink value="#{msg['recoveryPassword.msg.link']}" action="recoveryPass" />
                </h:form>
            </p>
```

On above example, my idea is to navigate to RecoveryPassword page from Login page and viceversa, and I would like email field reset value itself when I change view, but email never reset the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to clear the value in the `<transition>` or the `<on-entry>` of your states. Either with just a setter method or with a custom method (e.g. `reset()`). We do this for various other conditions where entering a state requires clearing a field.

e.g.

```
<view-state id="recovery">
    <on-entry>
        <set name="loginFields.email" value="''"/>
    </on-entry>
...
</view-state>
```